# How can I get my ASUS Transformer 101 to see upgrades?

Tags: asus-eee-pad-transformer

A group of us at work got ASUS Transformer 101's all at the same time.  (Now some of us are in the US, some are overseas).

I saw a note in our internal chat that ICS was available.  Yay, but I was away from home and left the pad at home.

So I got back a full week after my colleagues saw the update and charged it up, awaiting the upgrade to see the new hotness of ICS.

But Check for Firmware upgrades shows nothing available.  This happened before with 3.2.1 patches as well.

How do I troubleshoot the fact that my Transformer is not seeing the updates?  (I know how to get it from ASUS and apply it, since I had to do that for 3.2.1, but I want to stop having to work around it).

Comment: updates are usually rolled out in batches. maybe your batch of tablets hasn't been set to receive the update yet. Have you tried calling asus? they may be able to shed some light on the issue you are having.

Comment: I have the same problem. And worse: I couldn't install the update manually. I get some errors and the instalation is reversed. I guess I'll have to wait.

Comment: And suddenly this morning it saw the 9.2.1.17 update.  I had previously applied 9.2.1.11 manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fairly common issue apparently.

Here's how to fix it: [Link](http://www.transformerforums.com/forum/ice-cream-sandwich/16523-how-ics-update-problems-fix-them-these-steps.html)

Just killing the DMClient and CMClient services and rebooting did the trick for me. But disclaimer: Results may vary.