# ICS upgrade for Asus Transformer should be available OTA

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, asus-eee-pad-transformer

I can read everywhere here in France that the OTA version of Ice Cream Sandwich is available for the Asus Transformer TF101. But when I check for a new firmware, it finds nothing. Is there a step I missed?

My Transformer is currently working with Android 3.2.1.

Comment: Sounds similar to [How can I get my ASUS Transformer 101 to see upgrades?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20270/how-can-i-get-my-asus-transformer-101-to-see-upgrades) Also appears to be waiting for the ICS update.

Comment: I finally got it OTA yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OTA upgrade has been stopped due to several SW issues. A modified upgrade is expected within weeks, be patient.
(I do have the upgrade, but not installed as I have read about the problems... now I am refusing it every day :(

Comment: Ok, that's what I wanted to know. Could you add a link to the said problems?

Comment: Do you have a link to this information csababp ?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the [ASUS web site](http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?m=Eee%20Pad%20Transformer%20TF101&p=20&s=16), there are downloads available (choose Android as your OS. I got confused thinking that Windows was the right choice for the upgrade, they mean Windows for the drivers, and Android for the firmware).

Download the right localized build. I am in the US, so mine was the US build.

Copy it to an microSD card in a directory ASUS\Update\patchFile.zip

Then when you pop the card in, the tablet should notify you that there is an update available.

Comment: Right, here the link: http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?m=Eee+Pad+Transformer+TF101&p=20&s=16

Comment: geoffc - I should put in the sd card the file I directly downloaded or should I unzip it first?

Comment: @RafaelS.Calsaverini You unzip the first level file, should have a second ZIP'ed file in it.  Then you put that on the SD card in ASUS\Update directory and try it then.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but unfortunately my tablet is not groking the update. After some minutes it returns "There was a problem and the firmware was reversed to the previous state" or something like this. My eee pad is WW and I got the WW file. Maybe there was a problem with the download and a checksum error. Don't know. I will try again later. :(